# Get output from CallableStatement in JAVA

Tags: java, sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Hi I have created this code on my local Oracle DB server:

```
create or replace and compile java source named "demo1"
as
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Types;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;

public class demo1 extends Object
{
    public static java.lang.String DB_Exec(java.lang.String Conn_String,java.lang.String UserName,java.lang.String Pwd,java.lang.String SQL_Script) throws SQLException
    {
        java.lang.String DB_Output= new java.lang.String("");
        Connection c = null;
        CallableStatement cs = null;
        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
            c =  DriverManager.getConnection(Conn_String, UserName, Pwd);
            cs =  c.prepareCall(SQL_Script);

            cs.execute();

            DB_Output = "... here i need to have output log from cs.execute...";
            cs.close();
            c.close(); 
            return DB_Output;
        } catch (Exception e) {
           DB_Output = "JAVA ERROR:  " + e.getMessage();  
           return DB_Output;
        }finally{
            cs.close();
            cs=null;
        }
    }
}


create or replace function java_exec(Conn_String IN VARCHAR2,UserName IN VARCHAR2,Pwd IN VARCHAR2,SQL_Script IN VARCHAR2) return VARCHAR2
as language java name 'demo2.DB_Exec(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
```

Now I need to get to DB_Output property a "script output log" from the execution of custom SQL code on the oracle DB server (`cs.execute();`). Something like "Success" if the code was executed without error and error message if in the code is a bug.

The custom SQL code (in "SQL_Script" variable) for execution can be fully custom block of SQL statements (e.g. insert, update, ...).

Comment: Are you asking a way to retrieve a log generated by the DB ? Based on the "script" you are calling, their are different ways to retrieve a value or result set after the execution.

Comment: Yes I want to store log generated by the DB to the "DB_Output" property. For example if I send this script "Select 1/0 from dual" I want to get the "ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero" property.

Comment: You code does that already - if you pass the 'SQL script' as `'select 1/0 from dual'` the function does return "JAVA ERROR:  ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero". And with a non-erroring statement you get the ".. here I need to have ..." string, so you can just change that to "Success" if that's what you want to see. So - I'm not sure what you are asking or what problem you actually have.

Comment: It depends on what your SQL_Script looks like, but I assume you have considered cs.registerOutParameter, and something like cs.getString? It may be easier to create a wrapper function in PL/SQL, then pass the SQL_Script to be executed as dynamic SQL, then return relevant info back to the Java CallableStatement.